# Vectorization of numpy matrix that contains pdf of multiple gaussians and multiple samples

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, gaussian

My problem is this: I have GMM model with K multi-variate gaussians, and also I have N samples.
I want to create a N*K numpy matrix, which in it's [i,k] cell there is the pdf function of the k'th gaussian on the i'th sample, i.e. in this cell there is
In short, I'm intrested in the following matrix:
[pdf matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N2J5.png)

This what I have now (I'm working with python):

`Q = np.array([scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(mu_t[k], cov_t[k]).pdf(X) for k in range(self.K)]).T`

X in the code is a matrix whose lines are my samples.

It's works fine on small toy dataset from small dimension, but the dataset I'm working with is 10,000 28*28 pictures, and on it this line run extremely slowly...

I want to find a solution that doesn't envolve loops but only vector\matrix operation (i.e. vectorization). The scipy 'multivariate_normal' function cannot parameters of more than 1 gaussians, as far as I understand it (but it's 'pdf' function can calculates on multiple samples at once).

Does someone have an Idea?

Comment: As long as `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` only works for one `k` at a time, you can't "vectorize".  The slow speed is the result of calling that `pdf` many times.  Something `np.stack(..., axis=-1)`  can avoid the `.T` but doesn't really change the collection.  I haven't worked enough with `stats` to suggest a way of supplying more than one `gaussian` at a time.

Comment: There are a number of SO questions about this `normal` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid, that the main speed killer in your problem is the inversion and deteminant calculation for the cov_t matrices. If you somehow managed to precalculate these, you could enroll the calculation and use `np.add.outer` to get all combinations of `x_i - mu_k` and then use array comprehension to calculate the probabilities with the full formula of the normal distribution function.

Try

```
S = np.add.outer(X,-mu_t)
cov_t_inv = ??
cov_t_inv_det = ??
Q = 1/(2*np.pi*cov_t_inv_det)**0.5 * np.exp(-0.5*np.einsum('ikr,krs,kis->ik',S,cov_t_inv,S))
```

Where you insert precalculated arrays `cov_t_inv` for the inverse covariance matrices and `cov_t_inv_det` for their determinants.